# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when trying to build java-cef

Tags: java

I'm trying to build java-cef on ubuntu following instructions from https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding.

At cmake step

`cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..`

i get

```
-- Downloading clang-format from Google Storage...
Failed to fetch file gs://chromium-clang-format/942fc8b1789144b8071d3fc03ff0fcbe1cf81ac8 for tools/buildtools/linux64/clang-format. [Err: /home/x/Desktop/jcef/src/tools/buildtools/external_bin/gsutil/gsutil_4.15/gsutil/third_party/boto/boto/pyami/config.py:71: UserWarning: Unable to load AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE ()
  warnings.warn('Unable to load AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE (%s)' % full_path)
Failure: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:727).
]
```

Terminal indicates that I'm using Python 2.7.15+.

How can i make it work? Many thanks.

Comment: Me too facing this problem. I am also using Python 2.7.15+ on ubuntu 18. If you get the solution,plz share.

Comment: I added now the solution. I hope it helps. If not, i will come back with a complete solution when i get to have my laptop, after work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the folder where it has created the build `jcef/src/tools/buildtools/download_from_google_storage.py` change the version parameter of gsutil to a recent version, like `4.39`. If you don't find specified file use a tool like `find`.

Comment: it is working.                                                      !